# Is it possible to get the original number from DecimalForm?

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, export, machine-precision

**Bug introduced in 5.2 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0**
[CASE:4315787]

<sub>Wrong behavior of `NumberForm` (`DecimalForm` outputs the same) is confirmed by Wolfram techical support [CASE:4315787].</sub>

---

I'm trying to implement an efficient TSV exporter based on the code from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30797/280) answer. It works sufficiently quickly but the problem is that `OutputForm` shows about 6 most significant digits of a number, so I am forced to use `DecimalForm` to get all the digits as follows:

```
dat = RandomReal[{-100000, 100000}, {1000, 3000}];
PrependTo[dat, Table["header_" <> ToString[i], {i, 3000}]];

str = OpenWrite["speedtest.tsv"];
WriteString[str, DecimalForm[Row[#, "\t"], Infinity], "\n"] &~Scan~dat // AbsoluteTiming
Close[str];
```

But `DecimalForm` often drops the last digit of a number or changes it by 1 or rounds, here is an example (*Mathematica* 11.3):

```
DecimalForm[{-38741.90768741473, -7756.0224337393065, 
-39201.327646149446, -38666.237619983534, -7703.96642749069, 
-38539.13511093822, -38442.888322157516}, Infinity]
```

> ```
> {-38741.90768741472, -7756.022433739306, -39201.32764614944,
>  -38666.23761998353,-7703.966427490689,-38539.13511093823,-38442.88832215751}
> ```

One can see that the last digit of the first number is changed from 3 to 2, for the second, third and fourth numbers it is just dropped and so on... With `Export` everything works as expected but **very** slow:

```
ExportString[{-38741.90768741473, -7756.0224337393065, 
-39201.327646149446, -38666.237619983534, -7703.96642749069, 
-38539.13511093822, -38442.888322157516}, "TSV"]
```

> ```
> "-38741.90768741473
> -7756.0224337393065
> -39201.327646149446
> -38666.237619983534
> -7703.96642749069
> -38539.13511093822
> -38442.888322157516
> "
> ```

Is it possible to get the correct digits from `DecimalForm`? Or may be there is another efficient way to get in `OutputForm` all the digits for  numbers? Note that my table also contains strings which should be exported without extra quotes.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170889/38178) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171587/38178) might be of interest for you.

Comment: Alexey, I just edited the [C++ code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171587/38178). It works now without precision loss. Have a try.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you for your efforts. The method from the [first](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170889/280) link produces much more correct output than the method from my question if we increase the precision to 17, but in this case it produces also redundant digits due to the binary representation. I've found that we can get the same result (but 20% faster) if we increase the precision of the original numbers to 17 before exporting with the method from my question. I'll try the C++ solution when I install the compiler.

Comment: It looks like `Export` to `"Table"` merely applies `ToString[#, InputForm]&` to every number in the table for conversion into a string. So one workaround is the following change: `WriteString[str,Row[InputForm[#,NumberMarks->False]&/@#,"\t"],"\n"]&~Scan~dat`, but it is 10 times slower than the `DecimalForm` method (and 2 times faster than `Export`).

Comment: I don't have `DecimalForm` in version 10.1.  Do you find any use in converting `ToString` en masse and post processing?  Something like `StringReplace[
 ToString[dat, InputForm, PageWidth -> ∞], {", " -> "\t", 
  "{" -> "\n", "}" -> ""}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is almost as slow as `Export`.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Is `NumberForm` double rounding numbers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204359/280)"